# How to remove a subarray of size K to minimize the number of inversions in an array

Tags: algorithm

I know we can use merge sort's merging and dividing method to find inversions. But I was wondering about the most optimal way to remove a subarray such that the number of inversions are reduced.
We have to delete a subarray of size K. And I know a brute force approach where I keep on deleting subarrays of sizes k and keep on counting the inversions but that takes O(n^2) time. I need something in O(nlogn) or O(n)

Comment: We have to delete a subarray of size K. And I know a brute force approach where I keep on deleting subarrays of sizes k and keep on counting the inversions but that takes O(n^2) time. I need something in O(nlogn) or O(n)

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre]. Are you using c++ or python?

Comment: @Tyron Sequeria Sorry, I missed  `k size` in the title

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. This is neither a C++ question, nor a Python one.